# :after pseudo class not working when using in stylesheet and importing in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I am using `style-loader` and `css-loader` to import stylesheets in react:

```
require('../css/gallery/style.css');
```

The stylesheet's working fine, except for this rule:

```
.grid::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I already have a `div` which belongs to a the `grid` class here:

```
<div className="grid">
    {display_images}
</div>
```

The new element which should be created by the `:after` pseudoclass is not being created here. I know that React does not support pseudoclasses in its inline styles, but I don't know whether we are allowed to use them in stylesheets and then import them. If it isn't allowed, what are the alternatives?

Comment: This should work. Could you check in the `<style>` tag in the rendered DOM if the rule is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS-after that you have shown in your question doesn't display anything. I can't guarantee this is your solution without further investigation but I would recommend adding a temporary background colour so you can see the effect.

see the following JSFiddle for an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/o410b2h5/

```
.grid::after 
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
}
```

**background: red;**

Comment: I just checked using this method, and you're right, the `after` element exists. Should have thought about this sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single colon, not two: `.grid: after { /* your code*/ }`. Also ensure your class `.grid` has `position: relative`.